# Why is a NOLOCK query blocking reads/writes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have a view in SQL Server (2016) DB that uses NOLOCK hints for all the tables it selects from. We're finding that when this view is being consumed, it is actually blocking reads and writes.

According to [this](https://bertwagner.com/posts/how-nolock-will-block-your-queries/), a NOLOCK query issues a Sch-S lock and thus will only block things that, like DDL and re-index jobs. However, we're seeing DML read/write being blocked also, causing our whole app to go down. Why?

Note: the select from View query does not use NOLOCK hint, but not sure this should matter if the view itself is using NOLOCKs.

Note2: apologies for the light-on-facts question--I have limited privileges in the environment, and it's difficult to investigate using queries that require elevated permissions, so hoping for a purely theoretical analysis.

Thanks!

Comment: how have you proven that this view is indeed blocking? do you have an example of the blocking and blocked query? what is the isolation level of the blocked query?

Comment: i would also recommend whoever does have the appropriate permisions, downloads sp_whoisactive and runs it with @get_locks = 1 when the blocking situation is happening. It will show what query is blocking and on which object

Answer (score 1):

> Myth: NOLOCK / READ UNCOMMITTED means no locks
>
> First off, they're the same thing And they do have to acquire some
> locks:
>
> - Schema-stability locks (Sch-S) to prevent the structure of the table/index changing
> - BULK_OPERATION locks on heaps to prevent reading of unformatted pages
>
> And they still have to take latches to access the physical page
> images in memory, so there's still some potential for blocking at the
> latch level

https://tenbulls.co.uk/2011/10/14/nolock-hits-mythbusters/
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8627/shared-lock-issued-on-isolationlevel-readuncommitted

I have checked `BULK_OPERATION (HBT [BULK_OPERATION])` locks are easily reproduced for a table with no clustered index and select with nolock hint. If clustered index exists than HoBT lock is not applied.

So, it should be a rare case but still possible that using `WITH (NOLOCK)` you will have other queries blocked.

Answer (score 0):

From the [books online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15)

> NOLOCK is equivalent to READUNCOMMITTED.
>
> READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK cannot be specified for tables modified by
> insert, update, or delete operations. The SQL Server query optimizer
> ignores the READUNCOMMITTED and NOLOCK hints in the FROM clause that
> apply to the target table of an UPDATE or DELETE statement.

NOLOCK tells the server you are happy to read uncommitted data, allowing the user to retrieve the data without being affected by locks set by *other* queries; it doesn't mean "this query must not lock tables".

Without seeing your tables, data, and the query there’s limited help anyone can give.

Comment: This is a view, and it only contains SELECT statement, so there is no table modification. The article at link in your post says 'No shared locks are issued to prevent other transactions from modifying data read by the current transaction, and exclusive locks set by other transactions do not block the current transaction from reading the locked data.' This is the part I'm interested in.

Comment: Although a SELECT will (should) only obtain a shared lock it might be that the server escalates it and therefore blocks reads and writes to the tables used in your view. There’s information on investigating lock escalation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/resolve-blocking-problems-caused-lock-escalation

Answer (score 0):

You do understand that NOLOCK means that you don't care whether the data is transactionally consistent at the time you read it?  You know you can miss values, or read some values more than once?

If you want to ensure that READERS don't block WRITERS then investigate and learn concurrency and transaction isolation levels correctly and set the appropriate level. Read up on it at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Yes--I don't care that data can be inconsistent. This is for an aggregate report, where minor inconsistencies will not make material difference.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out there was indeed a query needing Schema Stability lock, which apparently was blocking threads in the app.

Comment: Good to hear you found the reason for the blocking.